# Terraform. Get value from AWS parameter store

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Can't understand how to get value from parameter store and pass it to the terraform variable.
I have a parameter with name "github_token" and "string" type. And there is a variable in terraform code

````
variable "github_oauth_token" {
  default=""
}

I tried to receive the value of parameter with next block of code, but it's not correct.

```hcl
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "github_token" {
  name = "github_token"
  type = "string"
  value = var.github_oauth_token
}
````

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Attempt to get attribute from null value; This value is null, so it does not have any attributes

Comment: That means either no AWS SSM parameter was able to be Read with those argument values, or is related to another part of your config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `data` source, you are not creating a new value, you are simply reading an existing value.  For that reason, specifying "value" and "type" doesn't make sense in this context because the value and the type of the parameter already exist.  If you take a look at [the data source aws_ssm_parameter documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ssm_parameter), you will see that the only thing that's required is the `name` value.

Assuming that:

1. The user that's running Terraform has permissions to access SSM (parameter store)
2. There's a value stored inside the parameter store at the path `github_token`
3. The value is not encrypted

This should work for you:

```
variable "github_oauth_token" {
    default = "github_token"
 }

data "aws_ssm_parameter" "github_token" {
  name = var.github_oauth_token
}
```

Then to use the value of the parameter store item:

```
data.aws_ssm_parameter.github_token.value
```